# android 8.1 plays random music sporadically and stops after 10 seconds or so

Tags: audio, music, silent-mode

I have an android phone that runs `8.1` and sporadically it will run some random music that I don't know of. It then stops on its own after a few seconds. My browser is turned off, and the phone is on vibrate. Checking the running processes in developer mode does not reveal anything suspicious. I also did not install any shady apps. What can I do to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: have you checked the `adb logcat` output for messages at the time the music was played?

Comment: @Robert Can I do this directly on the phone?

Comment: No. `adb` will only see all entries when accessing it from a PC.

Comment: Is it linked to notifications? Do you see any in notifications panel when this happens.?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed apps such as **UC Browser** and similar apps runs on background and plays audio on background. Just check your running apps and kill 3rd party app one by one to know which app is causing this issue. Another way is go to play store -> My apps -> Library and uninstall recently installed app to solve this issue.

Comment: The weird thing is, there were no recent apps installed. The issue is very sporadic, too, so it's hard to pin down if an app is causing it.